# Postmaster - Switching from Mandrill to SendGrid

Tags: email, postmaster

With Mandrill's new change of policies and pricing I'm moving away from using it for my transactional emails and am Switching to SendGrid.

I use the Postmaster add-on to trigger various emails as well as to send my EE system emails.

Switching the email service seems fairly straightforward, all I have to do is update each parcel and hook to use a new email service. I'm then required to enter my SendGrid username and password.

However it doesn't work.

Every email I try to send now get's this error:

> SendGrid Service - Error: The requested URL returned error: 400
>   Consult with SendGrid’s documentation for more information regarding
>   this error.

Unfortunately their documentation doesn't mention Error 400.

**Does anyone have experience with Postmaster using SendGrid as the email service? What do I need to do to get this working?!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Benek, i was in the same situation.. What i did was a bit simple (not sure if it's the best way or solution)

I simply hacked the Sendgrid.php located in /third_party/postmaster/services/Sendgrid.php

Modified

```
    public $url  = 'http://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json';
```

to

```
    public $url  = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json';
```

as stated on Sendgrid's api docs [Send Mail API page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html)

Ciao

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I did as well. I contacted the author of Postmaster and he informed me that his API integration may be outdated. So I quite easily found that line and update the API path. Works like a charm now.